# Is there a limit of elements in HTML (JSP)

Tags: java, html, jsp, limit, element

Basically I have a JSP that displays a div per each element that finds in a database. Of course the number of entries in the database varies, and I can't set a specific amount of divs to be displayed, so that's why we use JSP.
The thing is that I am developing the webpage now, and I've got to the point that my JSP doesn't display all of the divs that it should. I've done a lot of tests and it should work, and the Java part does work perfectly, but it seems that the problem comes when it gets to print out all the divs. In fact, not all of them, only the last ones, that's why I've come to think it might be that there's a limit in an HTML webpage or in a JSP.
Here is the part of the code that doesn't work correctly:

```
    for(int a=0;a<=lenhueco1-1;a++){
        id[a]="\"data1_"+a+" \"";
        titulo[a]="\"PIN: "+idn1[a]+" \"";
        out.println("<div title="+titulo[a]+"; id="+id[a]+"; class="+clase+"style="+estilo1[a]+"><span>"+id1[a]+"</span></div>");
        //out.println(posicion1[a]+":::"+id[a]+":::"+a);
    }

    for(int a=0;a<=lenhueco2-1;a++){
        id[a]="\"data2_"+a+" \"";
        titulo[a]="\"PIN: "+idn2[a]+" \"";
        out.println("<div title="+titulo[a]+"; id="+id[a]+"; class="+clase+"style="+estilo2[a]+"><span>"+id2[a]+"</span></div>");
        //out.println(posicion1[a]+":::"+id[a]+":::"+a);
    }

    for(int a=0;a<=lenhueco3-1;a++){
        id[a]="\"data3_"+a+" \"";
        titulo[a]="\"PIN: "+idn3[a]+" \"";
        out.println("<div title="+titulo[a]+"; id="+id[a]+"; class="+clase+"style="+estilo3[a]+"><span>"+id3[a]+"</span></div>");
        //out.println(posicion1[a]+":::"+id[a]+":::"+a);
    }

    for(int a=0;a<=lenhueco4-1;a++){
        id[a]="\"data4_"+a+" \"";
        titulo[a]="\"PIN: "+idn4[a]+" \"";
        out.println("<div title="+titulo[a]+"; id="+id[a]+"; class="+clase+"style="+estilo4[a]+"><span>"+id4[a]+"</span></div>");
        //out.println(posicion1[a]+":::"+id[a]+":::"+a);
    }
    if(diff>=6&&diff<=8){
    for(int a=0;a<diff;a++){
        id[a]="\"data5_"+a+" \"";
        titulo[a]="\"PIN: "+idn5[a]+" \"";
        out.println("<div title="+titulo[a]+"; id="+id[a]+"; class="+clase+"style="+estilo5[a]+"><span>"+id5[a]+"</span></div>");
        //out.println(posicion1[a]+":::"+id[a]+":::"+a);
    }
    }

   for(int a=0;a<=t5;a++){
       if(a<t1){
        posicion6[a]=56-step1*a;
        estilo6[a]="\"position: absolute; color:"+color6[a]+"; background-color:"+bcolor6[a]+"; border-color:"+borde+"; height:1.7vh ;top:"+posicion6[a]+"vh; left:1vw\"";
       }else if(a>=t1&&a<t2){
        posicion6[a]=20-40+step2*a;
        estilo6[a]="\"position: absolute; color:"+color6[a]+"; background-color:"+bcolor6[a]+"; border-color:"+borde+"; height:2.5vh;top:22.5vh;left:"+posicion6[a]+"vw\"";
       }
       out.println(a);
        id[a]="\"data6_"+a+" \"";
        titulo[a]="\"PIN: "+idn6[a]+" \"";
        out.println("<div title="+titulo[a]+"; id="+id[a]+"; class="+clase+"style="+estilo6[a]+"><span>"+id6[a]+"</span></div>");
        //out.println(posicion1[a]+":::"+id[a]+":::"+a);
    }
```

It gets perfectly through the first 4 "fors" and simply doesn't finish the last one.
Any knowledge about why this could happen?
I also would appreciate suggestions to get this done in some other way.
Thanks fellas!

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't finish the last one".

Comment: Doesn't finish the last loop for(int a=0;a<=t5;a++), it should print like about 130 divs and stops at 35 or so, and no, it's not a Java problem, i checked a thousand times and it should do 130 repetitions

Comment: Never heard of any limit for HTML elements before. Anyway you might wants to switch to JSTL and custom tags and avoiding mixing java and HTML. It's bad practice and as you can see it can get messy and hard to debug

Comment: The problem is that it's a work thing... and I really have to get it done this way (so that my coworkers can make any changes if they needed when my contract expires)

Comment: Try to change the if condition...what if a >= t2? Maybe the last iteration falls under that condition...Anyway it's not clear what for loop you are referring to in the question

Comment: Aupa @Asiertxo! Are you sure that all of your components exit? I mean, IdArray, StyleArray, and id6Array, have correct values? do that values have their correspondence on CSS?

Comment: Aupa ahi! Yes,they do, I get all their values if I print them out -without creating any div-, that's why this is so strange. In fact, I added a button to change the background colors of every div in my page and when I hit it, I get 3 or 4 more divs printed, but it's still not all of them.